# PHP PBKDF2 Password Hashing Code

Tags: php, passwords

I am just starting to use pbkdf2.

I've found this code here: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode which is free, but my question is:

What is the syntax to have a pbkdf2 password stored in db?

I mean for md5 you just had to type md5($_POST['Pass']) and it was done.

With this method how is it done? Do I include the code in my page and call it somehow?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

pbkdf2 basically does the same as md5, so to hash a password you would:

```
$encoded_password=create_hash($_POST['Pass']);
```

Comment: When you md5() you passwords in the past, use create_hash() instead. ie when creating the entry and checking it at login. Only at these points would you need to include the code (when used).

Comment: You mean I include the script only where I need to match the password eg with the username? And... cteate_hash is it used with the code I linked above??? NOw I am reading about bcrypt.. I am very confused

Comment: You've got it. include('pbkdf2.php'); $encoded_password=create_hash($_POST['Pass']); if you understand what md5 does, then that's basically it. Encrypt a password and store it, then to check: encrypt the login password and compare it against the stored one. You don't really need to understand how its done, just why its done.